# Applescript Paste and Tab From a Comma Delimited List

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to get an automator applescript to loop though a comma delimited list; and in doing so, paste value 1, tab, paste value 2, tab etc...

It doesn't seem to want to paste into a text field in google chrome however.

```
display dialog "What is the list? (Artist, Song Title, Artist, Song Title)" default answer "Frank Sinatra, My Way, Elvis, Blue Christmas"
set user_input to text returned of result

set {myTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, {","}}
set myList to text items of user_input -- Gives list {"2", "69", "12"}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to myTID -- It's considered good practice to return the TID's to their original state

repeat with myItem in myList -- Loop through the items in the list
    tell application "System Events"
        set the clipboard to myItem
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        keystroke tab
    end tell
    delay 1
end repeat

display dialog "Job Done"

return
```

Comment: Greetings, please don't post the working solution in your question, if that solution differs from pbell answer, then write another answer yourself with that content. Otherwise, flagging the answer as the accepted one and voting for it will do the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paste command is done on your script, not on other application (Chrome in your case). you must tell which process should receive the keystroke. Something like :

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Chrome"
Set the clipboard to myItem
keystroke "v" using {command down}
keystroke tab
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. For posterity, it works with 'Google Chrome'. I've updated the question with a working solution.